# Transactions design in Firebase with Firestore

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, design-patterns, database-design, google-cloud-functions

I am working on a project with Firestore + Cloud Function where a user's "credits" balance will be updated on many occasions.

For each update to the main balance we are maintaining a separate ledger in a separate collection with the details of all the movements (date, amounts etc.).

There are several areas of the codebase that interact with the balance.

I am contemplating using a Firestore background function with retries on to take care of updating my ledger on every update to the balance mainly to avoid duplication of logic throughout the codebase.

The tradeoff however is that what could be done in one transaction now needs two:
A) Transaction to update the balance (from wherever in the codebase)
B) Another transaction from the CF to log the details to the ledger

Is this a bad idea (if the CF is configured to retry)?

Thanks,

Comment: Do I understand correctly that there is ONE write to the separate collection each time there is ONE change in the main balance document. In other words you maintain a log of all the atomic modifications of the balance.

Comment: Hi @RenaudTarnec, that's correct.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly your question, you don't need to use two transactions. You can very well execute the two writes (one update and one creation) within the same Transaction, **as an atomic operation**.

Something along the following lines with the JS SDK:

```js
      const balanceDocRef1 = doc(db, 'balances', '....');
      const historyDocRef = doc(db, 'history', '....');

      try {
        await runTransaction(db, async (transaction) => {
          const balanceDoc = await transaction.get(balanceDocRef1);

          const newBalance = balanceDoc.data().balance + ....;

          transaction
            .update(balanceDocRef1, { balance: newBalance })
            .set(historyDocRef, { amount: '...', date: '...' });
        });
        console.log('Transaction successfully committed!');
      } catch (e) {
        console.log('Transaction failed: ', e);
      }
```

Comment: Hi @Stf_F, did you have the time to look at the proposed solution?